# What dark green and lime BIONICLE do I have?

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands, bionicle

[image]

If anybody could tell me what BIONICLE this is I’d greatly appreciate it, it’s driving me mad!

Answer (score 9):

My answer totally springboards off of [Alexander](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/5853/alexander-omara) "*Hawk-Eyes*" [O'Mara](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/5853/alexander-omara)'s astute observation of its suspected authenticity.  Nice job Alex.

I looked up BIONICLE knock-offs and got a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=3&v=GAWTWqm67pA) that named the brand as "конструктор последний воин", then Google Image searched that phrase for a pic of our Greenie Meanie, and *Voila!*:

[image]

Google translates the Russian/Mongolian to:

- "конструктор последний воин":

  "Builder of the Last Warrior".
- And this guy is named "ЛИЗОРД":

  "Lizord" or Lizard.
- The toy maker is, "1Toy Растем вместе!":

  "1Toy Growing Together!".

  [image]

There seems to be an entire, *Builder of the Last Warrior* line, with at least one dedicated community called *[RUSBIONICLE](https://www.google.com/search?q=rusbionicle&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1)*.

Comment: Impressive investigative work! I gave up after a Google image search yielded no results.

Comment: Thanks heaps Rin and Alexander! This was kinda surprising, but I was starting to suspect it may have been a knockoff. It just seemed like LEGO quality. Cheers 

Comment: Thank you for this! This question was keeping me up last night, and I just couldn't find a match. I started suspecting it was a clone, but I'm not familiar with clones for Bionicle sets. Great work by both you and Alexander!

Answer (score 6):

It's not a BIONICLE set or a LEGO set. The pins and axles aren't right for an official LEGO set, so I think this is some random BIONICLE-look-alike set by another brand.

LEGO pins would have a round center, not a flat one:

[image]

This axle hole in his hand appear rotated 45 degrees off the LEGO piece that looks like this.

[image]

I've never seen a LEGO piece that looked like this:

[image]